# Detect system hardware in browser

Tags: javascript, hardware, detect

Is there a way to detect system hardware trough the browser?
I want to write a program where people can click a button and it scans the system hardware (CPU, GPU, etc).

Is this possible? I tried searching on Google but didn't really find anything.

Comment: "Yes." But it depends on the OS and language/run-time. From Browser JavaScript? No - excepting what information is exposed via the browser (read: *maybe* the base architecture) or a custom extension.

Comment: Well, so I can get the information of the computer where the user is on. I'm want to make my own and open-source it http://www.systemrequirementslab.com/cyri

Comment: I assume you would like to do it from JavaScript. If that is true adding a JavaScript tag would be vital. However I'm almost sure it can be done, since scripts running in the browser should be platform independent, but I'm not sure since it is not my area of expertise.

Comment: Long story short: you cannot detect hardware capabilities in the browser, there's no API for that. You need additional plugins, like Java.

Comment: ...but Java is very limited in what it can access if it's not a signed jar, and even then it there are limits. Regarding the user agent string....its trivial to amend this.